# Spoof current MAC address to a known address to trick router and register device

Tags: arch-linux, internet, router, mac-address, spoofing

I want to connect to a device to the internet, a `Roku player`, that has its own `MAC` address.

The network that I currently have access to requires that I login using my credentials prior to being connected to the Internet. The process is such that the first time you try to access a website you are forwarded to a "login" page, where you enter your credentials.

The problem is that the `Roku player` does not have a browser, which I can use to do this step. So when I attempt to use the device it just sits.

Even though I am *connected* to the Internet, I do not have *access* to it through the router. So I was thinking that it may work, if I used my laptop to spoof my `MAC` address to the specific address of my `Roku player` and login that way to register this device.

Would this work? If so, how could I go about doing it?

Comment: Have you [tried ifconfig](http://linuxg.net/3-ways-to-temporary-change-the-mac-address-in-linux-and-unix/)?

Comment: [NetworkManager](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=553771) has support for this.

Answer (score 6):

Spoofing your `MAC`-Address is relatively simple:

General steps:

1. Save your `MAC` for a future reset
2. Temporary disable your interface to change your `MAC`
3. Set your new, arbirtray `MAC`
4. Enable your interface again

Using different tools:

---

- With `ip`:

  1. `ip link show <interface> &> ip_savehafen.log`
  2. `sudo ip link set dev <interface> down`
  3. `sudo ip link set dev <interface> address <new MAC address>`
  4. `sudo ip link set dev <interface> up`

---

- With `ifconfig`:

  1. `ifconfig <interface> | head -n1 &> ic_savehafen.log`
  2. `sudo ifconfig <interface> down`
  3. `sudo ifconfig <interface> hw ether <new MAC address>`
  4. `sudo ifconfig <interface> up`

Sources [1](http://linuxg.net/3-ways-to-temporary-change-the-mac-address-in-linux-and-unix/) [2](http://blog.up-link.ro/how-to-change-mac-address-in-linux-bsd-unix/) [3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_Address_Spoofing)

Also learn more abut [ARP-Spoofing](http://www.allguru.net/security/running-network-sniffer-dsniff/) [:)](http://docs.oseems.com/general/operatingsystem/linux/sniff-network-traffic)

Comment: Need term/telnet and root access, Roku's are locked down

Comment: No need to save your old mac, as soon as you reboot your machine your old mac will be back. Maybe you can get it back without rebooting but not sure about that.

Comment: @bdowning - Doesn't matter that Roku's are locked down - the OP was asking about spoofing the MAC address of his laptop, to make it match the MAC of his Roku.  For that, he only needs root on the laptop.

Comment: @YoMismo - Sure, rebooting would work, but isn't that harder than changing it back to the original address by following the same procedure as you used to change it to a different address temporarily?

Comment: @godlygeek exactly :). Saving your MAC adress is for a temporary change-back.

Comment: @godlygeek no need. Acording to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955504/finding-original-mac-address-from-hardware-itself you can check the permanent address with `ethtool -P eth0` changing eth0 by your interface. It is not necessary to save it, your network adapter has its own mac hardcoded inside :)

Comment: @YoMismo, it makes sense that the adapter needs to know it's own MAC, but I didn't realize it was able to be queried.  Good to know!

Comment: @bdowning what do you mean?

Comment: Never mind, it was my misunderstanding. I thought you were trying to change the MAC of the Roku box.